# How common is life insurance with tech jobs in Canada?

Tags: canada, insurance, technology

I need to get an idea of how common it is for tech jobs in Canada to offer life insurance policies. I know from experience that, in the US, this is a really common thing, but I haven't been able to find much in the way of statistics about it.

Comment: It's an employer based benefit.  It's common for larger employers not so much for small ones.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Open Text, which is the biggest Canadian owned software company. We're based out of Waterloo, ON with offices in Montreal, Ottawa, Richmond Hill, Toronto, Waterloo and Calgary.

We offer live insurance as part of our benefits. I think it is twice my yearly fixed income and double that if I die in an accident. But I think there are a lot of conditions connected to the payout. I don't really care because my kids are grown up by now and as an immigrant from Germany I never understood why people here go in so much debt (mortgage excluded of course).

I'm not sure you'll get a better response in this group. You ask "how common is it in Canada" - that's a question you need to ask somebody who's got a view on the industry.

I'd think that it is not really something you should spend too much time on: Find out what the coverage you're going to need will cost you in Canada and if your potential employeur doesn't offer this type of benefit then you have to add it to your salary.

Comment: I've worked for a number of Canadian companies. Bigger ones will often offer this, but smaller ones frequently won't. But Steffen is right that it shouldn't be a big factor in your job selection.